# Xcode build fails 'Foundation/NSURLHandle.h' file not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The issue only occurs on "real" device builds.

I already tried a reinstall of Xcode. I even switched my mac from a Intel to Apple silicon without using any backups.

My coworkers can build without any issue.

I am on Xcode `14.3.1 (14E300c)` and macOS `13.5.1 (22G90)`

Full error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURL.h:10:9 'Foundation/NSURLHandle.h' file not found
```

If I search for the issue I find no helpful results so this is my last hope here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` in my `.zshrc`.

unsetting it, resolved the problem.